# Display HTML elements based on user authentication with sessions in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, session

I have a website for which I have two types of user, admin and regular.  The type of user is tracked using sessions in node.js.  In some cases, I want both to have access to the same webpage, but want some buttons or graphics to only appear to the admins.  I'm aware that I can use client-side javascript to change the buttons/graphics to hidden in certain cases, but I can't figure out how to get information from my node.js backend to the client-side javascript so admin status can be verified when the page is loaded.

Comment: One of the easier ways would be to make an asynchronous call to your API (on, for example `/api/whoami`), and have your API tell the client about its permissions. But really the best way is completely dependant upon the architecture of your app, and without any insight into that, making a more tailored recommendation/suggestion is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by API and architecture?  I'm using a node.js backend with MongoDB as my user database and sessions as my session handler.